# Reading and writing from files with a new form

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read from a file and I have to use a new form of it I'm not really certain how to use. I've posted the code below of what function I have and I'm not sure what to do about this error and how to fix it?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double* read_file(FILE* file, int length);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double* array = malloc(10 * sizeof(double));
    int length = atoi(*(argv + 1));
    FILE* file = *(argv + 2);

    if (argc < 4 || argc > 4)
    {
        printf("Insufficient arguments. Check your command line.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    array = read_file(file, length);
    printf("%p", array);
    return 0;
}

double* read_file (FILE* file, int length)
{
    FILE* ptr;
    double* array = malloc(length * sizeof(double));

    int i = 0;

    if ((ptr = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            fscanf(ptr, "%lf", (array + i));
        }
    }

    fclose(ptr);

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code by text, not by image.

Comment: Image only code questions/answers are not acceptable on this site, for various reasons - links go out of date, no one can copy, build, experiment, enhance your code to reply, etc... Please edit your question, cut/paste the actual code into the the Stack Overflow question editor window, indented 4 spaces so it shows up as a formatted code block. if you need to indent with an external editor first that's fine, or use cmd-K in the Stack Overflow edit window. See the ? help in the icon bar of the edit window to find out how to format questions and answers properly.

Comment: @BradyWebb Since you are new recommend taking the [2 Minute Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a good question here (also increases your chances of getting an answer)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're trying to assign a *char string* to a variable of type *pointer to FILE*. The compiler won't let you do that.

```
// not allowed
FILE* file = *(argv + 2);
```

Secondly, you're passing a *pointer to FILE* to `fopen()`, but `fopen()` expects it's first argument to be a *char string* so that won't work either.

```
// file is FILE*, not allowed
ptr = fopen(file, "r"));
```

If you fix those two lines the code should compile.

Answer (score 0):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//double* read_file(FILE* file, int length);
//You do not need to pass a file pointer, you need a file name.
//It opens the file within this function
double *read_file(const char *filename, int length);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //if (argc < 4 || argc > 4)
    //argc < 4 || argc > 4 same as argc != 4
    //It is thought that it is 3 because only argv[1] and argv[2] are used.
    //It is necessary to check arguments before using them.
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage : %s number_of_elements file_name\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Insufficient arguments. Check your command line.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //double* array = malloc(10 * sizeof(double));//It is not necessary as it is secured by read_file. Make memory leak.
    int length = atoi(argv[1]);
    const char *file = argv[2];

    double *array = read_file(file, length);
    if(array != NULL){
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            printf("%f\n", array[i]);
        free(array);
    }
    return 0;
}

double* read_file (const char *file, int length){
    FILE *ptr;

    if ((ptr = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    //It causes a memory leak unless you first confirm that the file can be opened
    double *array = malloc(length * sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(1 != fscanf(ptr, "%lf", array + i)){
            printf("Failed to read the %ith element.\n", i+1);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(ptr);

    return array;
}
```